# Permanent cookies

Tags: asp.net, ajax, cookies

I am trying to re-create the functionality seen on 43things.com, where you enter a text and it gets added to the list below and also brings up "123 people want to do this". This entry seems to be permanently stored when you are visiting the site from your machine.

I am just wondering how this works? Is it just a cookie placed on the user's machine?

I also wanted to know how I could do the text addition in Ajax rather than having to postback?
For ex. I just want an entry to be made and the "xxx want to do this" displayed as soon as the text has been submitted, like how it works with Facebook comments. Is there a component in AJAX control toolkit for ASP.net for this - I couldn't seem to find one?

Answer (score 0):

They simply store that information in their database. Every visitor has a unique id or is signed in. they could store a cookie to recognize frequent visitors.

For the second part you want to use UpdatePanels `<asp:UpdatePanel />`